# How to apply filter number to input value | Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to apply angular's filter number to input value directly.

I thought the code below must work, but it doesn't..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.price" value="{{product.price | number}}" required>
```

Is it possible to implement this by default Angular resources? Without writting directives?

Comment: use ng-pattern for this..

Comment: ng-patter is more for validation purposes I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achived using regex or ng-pattern.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.price" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" required>
```

2.If you want to format the data value, you can do something like this.

```
$scope.product.price= parseInt($scope.product.price)
```

Comment: It must format the input value like Angular's filter number. Your code doesn't do this..

Comment: if you want to format your data value to number, do this in controller itself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `value` attribute when you have the `ng-model` attribute:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.price" required>
```

Set the value of `product.price` in the controller.  If you want to format the price, do it in the controller as well.